# WebView shows black screen when video file exists and alert shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have used a UIWebView to show an url over that. It works fine but client said to download video and save it into photo gallery.i have written code for downloading video from UIWebView and saving it to photo gallery. But i have written a condition, if user clicked on a video that is already downloaded and saved to photo gallery,to show an alert that file is already saved.then i see on that when this message is shown in the same time there is black screen appears on the view same as media player . so my question is that- How to Control or remove that black screen from web view  i have removed black screen by reloading same UIWebView but this is not fulfilling my requirement so please help me... Please.. Please

Here is my code for showing url on UIWebView and saving video file

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface WebViewController ()
{
  NSURL *theRessourcesURL;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastURL;
@property(nonatomic,strong)MBProgressHUD *hud;
@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

BOOL isLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation);
BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
if(isLandscape)
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (screenRect.size.height > 500)
        {
            webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 568, 300)];
        }
        else
        {
            webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 480, 300)];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 1004, 748)];
    }
    NSLog(@"isLandscape");
}
else if (isPortrait)
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (screenRect.size.height > 500)
        {
            webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548)];
        }
        else
        {
            webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 768, 984)];
    }

}

[webView setDelegate:self];
webView.tag = 999;
for (UIView* subView in webView.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        currentScrollView = (UIScrollView *)subView;
        currentScrollView.delegate = (id) self;
    }
}

//demo url
NSString *fullURL = @"http://demo.php.anuj.com/videoapp-t/home";



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

pull = [[PullToRefreshView alloc] initWithScrollView:currentScrollView];
[pull setDelegate:self];
pull.tag = 998;
[currentScrollView addSubview:pull];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

}

-(void)pullToRefreshViewShouldRefresh:(PullToRefreshView *)view {

  [(UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:999] reload];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
BOOL isLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation);
BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
if(isLandscape)
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (screenRect.size.height > 500)
        {
            webView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 20, 568, 300);
        }
        else
        {
           webView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 20, 480, 300);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        webView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 20, 1004, 748);
    }
    NSLog(@"isLandscape");
}
else if (isPortrait)
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (screenRect.size.height > 500)
        {
           webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548);
        }
        else
        {
            webView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        webView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 20, 768, 984);
    }

    }
  }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

} 

#pragma mark - webview

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
   MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
   hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
   hud.labelText = @"Loading...";

}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
   [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];
 }

 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
     AppDelegate *appdel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [appdel.reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
      if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
      {
           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Anuj Demo"   message:@"Internet connection required. Please check connectivity to internet." delegate:nil   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
          [alert show];
   }
     else
    {
      //        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Anuj Demo" message:@"Internet connection required. Please pull to refresh." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      //          [alert show];
    }
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];

   }

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
  if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )
  {
    theRessourcesURL = [inRequest URL];
    NSString *fileExtension = [theRessourcesURL pathExtension];

    if ([fileExtension isEqualToString:@"mp4"] || [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"mov"] || [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"m4v"])
    {
        // Get the filename of the loaded ressource form the UIWebView's request URL

        NSString *filename = [theRessourcesURL lastPathComponent];
        NSLog(@"Filename: %@", filename);

        NSFileManager *filemanager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

        BOOL success =[filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path];

        if (success ==TRUE) {
            UIAlertView *filenameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reel Africa" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The file %@ already exists.", filename] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [filenameAlert show];

    // Here if i reload webview then it works otherwise giving black screen on webview  like media player( [webview reload])

        }
        else
        {
            [self performSelector:@selector(saveVideoTOPhotoAlbum) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        }
    }
    else if([fileExtension isEqualToString:@"wmv"] || [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"3gp"] || [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"3G2"])
    {
        UIAlertView *filenameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anuj Demo" message:@"iPhone does not support this vedio format." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [filenameAlert show];
    }
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[inRequest URL]];
    if ([tempString rangeOfString:@"?ultima"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
  }
   return YES;
  }

  -(void)saveVideoTOPhotoAlbum
   {
  NSString *filename = [theRessourcesURL lastPathComponent];
  NSLog(@"Filename: %@", filename);
  // Get the path to the App's Documents directory
  NSString *docPath = [self documentsDirectoryPath];
  // Combine the filename and the path to the documents dir into the full path
  NSString *pathToDownloadTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, filename];
  // Load the file from the remote server
  NSData *tmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theRessourcesURL];
  // Save the loaded data if loaded successfully
    if (tmp != nil) {
      NSError *error = nil;

      [tmp writeToFile:pathToDownloadTo options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

      // Write the contents of our tmp object into a file

      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
       NSString *getImagePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
      printf(" \n\n\n-Video file == %s",[getImagePath UTF8String]);
      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum ( getImagePath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);

     if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save the file: %@", [error description]);
    } else {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        // Display an UIAlertView that shows the users we saved the file :)
        UIAlertView *filenameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anuj Demo" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The file %@ has been saved.", filename] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [filenameAlert show];
     }
    }

}

  - (void) video: (NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo
 {

   NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error);
   //Anuj here ****
  }

- (NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   return documentsDirectoryPath;
}


 @end
```

Comment: If you want to only download the video why use webview ?

Comment: Hi, goodsp33d, webview is also used to show page of given url and playing video inside that and downloading,saving....not only downloading

Answer (score 0):

If file exist, you should return NO. try it.

Comment: hi, trick i have already used that but still facing same problems.